# Using await as an argument

Tags: javascript, async-await

Just wondering if this is do-able (I assume not because I have never seen it done anywhere) and if anyone has a good explanation as to why not.

```
const expiry = new Date(await getTokenExpiry() * 1000)
```

Or whether I have to do it like this:

```
const expiry = await getTokenExpiry()
const muhExpiry = new Date(expiry * 1000)
```

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: As to the why, are you familiar with the way async/await boils down to .then as syntactic sugar?

Comment: `await` evaluates to an expression. It itself is an expression, so yes it is doable.

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Second example is what you get with first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done - arguments are evaluated before their outer expressions, after all, which goes hand-in-hand with `await`, should you need it. For example:

```js
const multiplyBy4 = num => num * 4;
const resolveWithOne = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 500, 1));

(async () => {
  console.log('start');
  const result = multiplyBy4(await resolveWithOne());
  console.log(result);
})();
```

That said, unless the expression is *quite trivial*, code would probably be a bit more readable if you put each `await` on its own line.

Comment: Hey CertainPerformance, thank you for your clear and straight-forward explanation  Helped me so much, have a great day! 